# Can node js calculate the value of two input fields and update another field?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to calculate the value of two input fields values using nodejs and update a answer field

```
<input type="text" name="number">
<input type="text" name="number">
<input type="text" name="answer">
```

I have seen it done with jquery and was wondering if the same would be possible with nodejs?

Comment: `node` runs on the server - jQuery is client-side.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? you can send the form via AJAX (using e.g. jQuery), then process it with node.js and send back to your browser

Comment: Do you understand the basics of front-end / back-end ?

Comment: It's feasible with Web Sockets, e.g. with Socket.io. By broadcasting the values to server and then broadcast updated result back.

Although I don't know why would you like to do this? Maybe some kind of security scenario?

Comment: Yes I understand the basics, sorry my question didn't specify. I'd like node to process the calculation and send it back to the browser.

Comment: You have to send the two values to the sever and update the third field with the repsonse from the server, but yes, Node.js can certainly add two numbers, or whatever calculation you want to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is no, not on its own.

Node.js runs on the server side of things.  A form, like in your example, runs on the client (the browser).  You'd still need to run some other client-side javascript to at least send the fields back to the node server app to calculate them.

What you might be looking for instead is a system like AngularJS on the client side that would provide a bit more structure.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ8DJf?p=preview

Here's the javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value1 = 'Hello';
  $scope.value2 = 'World';

  $scope.$watch('value1', updateValue3);
  $scope.$watch('value2', updateValue3);

  function updateValue3() {
        $scope.value3 = $scope.value1 + ' ' + $scope.value2;  
  }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.10"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label for="">Value 1<input ng-model="value1"></label><br>
    <label for="">Value 2<input ng-model="value2"></label><br>
    <label for="">Value 3<input ng-model="value3"></label><br>

    You don't need an input to show the value, either: {{value3}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed to start me off

Answer (score 0):

If instead you actually want it to be done on the server side, using node.js, then you would have to create a separate node application, expose some sort of REST interface/API, and use client side Javascript to make an HTTP call to the node application for computing the answer.  That's far more than somebody can demo in a Plunk.

Though if you are interested in something like that, you can use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to scaffold some basic multi-tier apps like that as a starting point.  As I like to use AngularJS, I often use [AngularFullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

AngularFullstack will give you the basics for creating a client side app that interfaces with a node server side application, along with helping you create the routes that will define the REST interface you'd use and how you would have the client side app access resources in the node portion on the server side.